# vertical-align after pull-right in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the element which is pulled right to be vertical-aligned, but I didn't succeed, I've been searching online for a while, some say that I should also specify a `line-height` value, but it didnt' work for me.

```css
.float-vertical-align {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sample</a>
    </div>
    <div class='pull-right float-vertical-align'>
      <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use a negative margin-top in your css: margin-top: -40px; for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`vertical-align` is not meant to be used with block elements](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html).

> The confusion, in my opinion, sets in when people try to use vertical-align on block level elements and get no results. If you have a small div inside a larger div and want to vertically center the smaller one within, vertical-align will not help you. - [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

Here's a possible solution and [common pattern](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical3) for vertical centering:

```css
.float-vertical-align {
  border: 1px solid red;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sample</a>
    </div>
    <div class='float-vertical-align'>
      <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The vertical-align: middle; property is useful only for images and one line of text to make it vertically align: middle But Using bootstrap navbar-right and applying padding to it will be one way or you can also apply [FlexBox trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410490/align-images-vertically-in-jquery-bxslider-plugin/36644182#36644182) to make it vertically middle aligned.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Or, just after fiddling around, you can do something like this:

Note: I just mimiced the styles from the computed elements. This method has no scaling utility, so you'd have to add that in (I won't pretend that it makes sense to me, so I'm not going to try it).

```css
.navbar-right.navbar-div {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sample</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-right navbar-div">
      Some variety of text
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the `.pull-right` command doesn't work very well on boostrap navigations, unfortunately.

From what I know of bootstrap, this is the fastest way to get pure text on the right side of the screen. It involves using `.navbar-right` on a `<ul>` element as well as `.navbar-text` on a `<span>` element.

There's probably other ways to do this, but if you're looking for minimal effort, this is probably it.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sample</a>
    </div>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
      <li><span class="navbar-text">Right Text</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```