# Why won't my div align vertically?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So, I wan't the wrapper-adds to be on top of one another, but I want the wrapper-diary div to be beside the two. I'm not exactly sure why wrapper-diary won't align next to the two divs because they are all within the same wrapper. The margins denote that they should be able to align the way I want them to, but they won't for some reason.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-add">  
  <div id="addFood3">
    <!--stuff-->
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="wrapper-add">
    <div id="addFood2">
    <!--stuff-->
    </div>
  </div>
 <div id="wrapper-diary">
      <!--stuff-->
 </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#addFood3{
  margin-top:75px; 
  margin-bottom:75px; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  margin-left:13%; 
  border-width:2px; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ABABAB; 
  padding:10px 10px; 
  float:left;
  background:#FFFFFF; 
  width:235px; 
  border-radius:3px;
}

#addFood2{
  margin-top:40px; 
  margin-bottom:40px; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  margin-left:13%; 
  border-width:2px; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ABABAB; 
  padding:10px 10px; 
  float:left;
  background:#FFFFFF; 
  width:235px; 
  border-radius:3px;
}

#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
}

#wrapper-add{
  width:25%;
  height:260px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper-diary{
  width:74%;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:25%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0%;
  z-index:-3;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing div tag. Could you check if it's in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I typed it it, but for some reason it wasn't showing up as code, but it's in my actual code.

Comment: `<div>` elements are block elements. Block elements are placed below preceding elements rather than side-by-side (in-line, like `display: inline;` elements). If you want them to display next to each other on the same line, you need to apply `display: inline-block;` to your two divs, like https://jsfiddle.net/6yh7qcos/

Comment: In stead of using margin use flexbox trick. [Flexbox trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410490/align-images-vertically-in-jquery-bxslider-plugin/36644182#36644182)

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you so much, @TylerH !